# Order the functions below by increasing order

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I am confused by a homework problem I have concerning asymptotic growth rates.

A subset of the problem is to order:

$n^a(0 < a < 1)$

and $ln(n)$

by increasing growth rates

It was proposed to me that as n approaches $infinity$, then $n^a$ also approaches $infinity$, but I argue that $a$ can grow closer and closer to zero, keeping n close to one.  As $a$ grows closer to 1 then n^a approaches infinity.

How do I order this function in regards to $ln(n)$ since the value of $n^a$ can be either above or below $ln(n)$ based on the value of $a$?

Comment: You are right when saying you could choose $a$ small enough so that the logarithm curve and the curve of $x \longmapsto a^x$ intersect. Here $a$ is a parameter and is fixed independently from $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The homework  question asks for  ranking  **asymptotic growth rates**, not ranking function themselves.

Derivatives of these two functions:

$\frac{dn^a}{dn}$=$a(n^{a-1})$, $\frac{dln(n)}{dn}$=$\frac{1}{n}$

set S = $a(x^{a-1})$ -$\frac{1}{x}$ =0, $x^a$=$\frac{1}{a}$,x= $a^{-\frac{1}{a}}$

When n > $a^{-\frac{1}{a}}$, $n^a$ grows faster, the order is ln(n),$n^a$;

When   n < $a^{-\frac{1}{a}}$, $n^a$ grows slower, the order is $n^a$,ln(n).

Comment: I think your last inequality is the wrong way around (at least for $n>1$)

Comment: @sal, thanks! Corrected.